# Static directory file browsing ending too early

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I'm currently making a little site to host a large set of UAV image mosaics and want someone who comes in to be able to go through the data folder structure I have been given to find their data. However, I'm aborting before I get to any files. The following code gives the 404 error when I am 3 folders in past "2017 Data." In some cases, this is 1 or 2 folders above where the images are stored.

```
from flask import Flask, abort, send_file, render_template_string
import os
import remoteSensingData

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'req_path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:req_path>')
def dir_listing(req_path):
    BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath("/Users/Huang.LabTech2/Desktop/Images/2017 Data/")

    # Joining the base and the requested path
    abs_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, req_path)

    # Return 404 if path doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(abs_path):
        return abort(404)

    # Check if path is a file and serve
    if os.path.isfile(abs_path):
        return send_file(abs_path)

    # Show directory contents
    files = os.listdir(abs_path)
    files = [os.path.join(req_path, f) for f in files]
    # return render_template('files.html', files=files)
    return render_template_string("""
    <ul>
        {% for file in files %}
        <li><a href="{{ file }}">{{ file }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    """, files=files)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

I have further issues with getting towards my end goal, but they aren't related to this issue, so I will form separate questions for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by the whitespace in your `BASE_DIR` path.

You can easily prove it by renaming your folder from 2017 Data to 2017_Data
or you can try to use:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(r"/Users/Huang.LabTech2/Desktop/Images/2017 Data/")
```

Comment: Neither of those fixed the problem, but thanks for responding.

Comment: What operating system do you use? The problem is with your BASE_DIR - try to log the `abs_path` to the console and you will be able to see what is wrong. My second assumption is the missing drive letter (in case you are using windows) e.g: "C:/Users/.."

Comment: I am using Windows 10. I've narrowed the problem down to the os.path.isfile(abs_path) lines not working, but I am unsure how to fix them. For example, if I join the BASE_DIR with the folder containing a set of images (C:\Users\Huang.LabTech2\Desktop\Images\2017 Data\UAV\Bobby_Hardin_Multi(8-16)\3_dsm_ortho\2_mosaic), abs_path joins the images and gives me the correct path. but os.path.isfile(abs_path) returns false.